# SAS: How to calculate frequency for all character variables except some

Tags: sas

I know I can have something like the following to calculate frequency for all Chars:

```
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables _char_;
run;
```

However, is there a way to exclude some variables? I want to do something like:

```
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables _char_ EXCEPT VAR1 VAR2;
run;
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

you can use drop = , as shown below.

> ```
> proc freq data=sashelp.cars(drop=origin make);
>   tables _char_;
>    run;
> ```

Comment: Thank you Kiran! I don't know we can use drop in proc freq before!

Answer (score 0):

The drop example is the simplest, certainly, and probably best if that's exactly the request.

However, if it's slightly different - such as, you want to include (or exclude) all character variables matching a particular pattern, you can use macro variables constructed from dictionary.columns (or proc contents output dataset).

```
proc sql;
  select name 
    into :freqlist separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where memname='YOURTABLE' and libname='YOURLIB'
    and type='char' and name like 'PATTERN%'
  ;
quit;
```

Obviously filling in the various uppercase things as appropriate.  Usually MEMNAME, LIBNAME, and NAME are stored upper case, though not always, so consider adding UPCASE() to them.

Then you can put `&freqlist.;` on the tables statement to get the list of columns that match your query.

Comment: This is the high end solution. It works like a charm!