# How do I write a macro to count the number of occurrences for a variable?

Tags: macros, sas

I have a dataset with multiple variable, and I want to write a macro that will count the number of specific observations for each variable.

Example:

### Variable: Strength

```
          1
          1
          2
          1
          2
          3
```

I want to count how many 1s, 2s, and 3s, there are for strength. I want to do the same for the rest of the variables with a macro.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS: How to calculate frequency for all character variables except some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712856/sas-how-to-calculate-frequency-for-all-character-variables-except-some)

Answer (score 0):

How about using proc sql for this instead of Macros.

```
data str;
input strength 1.;
datalines;
1
1
2
1
2
3
;
run;

proc sql;
create table str_count
as
select strength, count(strength) as count_str
from str
group by strength;
quit;

proc print data=str_count; run;
```

Proc SQl is also SAS functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use PROC FREQ. By default, without a table statement it will prepare a frequency report for all variables. If you want it in a table, try the ODS statement which generates the WANT data set.

ods output onewayFreqs = WANT;
   proc freq data=sashelp.class;
   run;